# What will be the query for the following query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qsqlquery, mysql-select-db

```
SELECT s.subject_id
     , s.subject_name
     , t.class_id
     , t.section_id
     , c.teacher_id
  FROM school_timetable_content c
  JOIN s  
    ON c.subject_id = s.subject_id
  JOIN school_timetables t 
    ON t.timetable_id = c.timetable_id
 WHERE c.teacher_id = 184
   AND t.class_id = 24
   AND t.school_id = 28
```

From the above query, I get the following result shown below:-

[image: Result for the above query]

again from the above result I want to get **subjects** which are associated with all the unique **section_id 15, 16,26**. i.e Expected output **Hindi,Maths**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This question is quite clear.  I have no idea why someone would close it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no MCRE and an image

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to filter for exactly those three sections.  Then aggregate and count if all three are present:

```
SELECT s.subject_id, s.subject_name
FROM school_timetable_content tc JOIN
     school_subjects s
     ON tc.subject_id = s.subject_id JOIN
     school_timetables t
     ON t.timetable_id = tc.timetable_id
WHERE tc.teacher_id = 184 AND 
      t.class_id = 24 AND
      t.school_id = 28 AND
      t.section_id IN (15, 16, 26)
GROUP BY s.subject_id, s.subject_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

This assumes that `section_id` is not duplicated.  If that is possible, use `HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT section_id)) = 3` instead.

Note that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.